# Highlight table view cells when user drags across rows

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a grouped table view that does not need to scroll. I'd like each cell to highlight as the user moves their finger down the screen and call didSelectRowAtIndexPath on release.

This behaviour can be seen done by apple in 'settings > mail > add account'?

I can't seem to replicate it myself, all I can get is the default, where the cell deselects as soon as the user moves their finger.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way that that example is done is not a UITableView, instead i think they draw the "table" from buttons. This would then not allow the scrolling feature while allowing you to have the buttons highlighted.

Hope this pushed you in the right direction.

Seb kade